# How to multiplicate ROOM database's columns with edit text

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, android-room

I have a question if there is any option to calculate data from column in ROOM with editable Edit Text in adapter?
Adapter:

```
class AdapterList (context: Context, val resource: Int, val objects: List<Opryski>) :
    ArrayAdapter<Opryski>(context, resource, objects){
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    val customView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false)
    val area= customView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextSize)
    val dose= customView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.id_dose)
    val name= customView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.id_nazme)
    val what= customView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.id_what)
    val when= customView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.id_when)
    val profilaktyka = customView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.id_profilaktyka)

    val item = objects.getOrNull(position)
    if(item!=null)
    {
        name.text = item.name
        dose.text = item.dose.toString() * area //<--- I want to multiplicate this//
        what.text = item.what
        when.text = item.when
        profilaktyka.text = item.profilaktyka
    }
return customView
}
```

}

EditText is in activity_main.xml as place where we can type our area and program should show a list of calculated dose of pesticide needed to this area

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it with a query and also have an intermediate Model for doing it so:

Room is a SQLite wrapper, so mostly all valid on SQLite is valid for ROOM

```
//I'm using a raw string here, triple quotes so I can write without minding the line breaks
@Query("""SELECT 
name as name,
what as what,
when as when,
(dose * :area) as multiplication
FROM Opryski
""")
fun observeOpryskiesWithCalculatedDose(area: Int): LiveData<DosedOpryski>
```

So as you can see there is `something as something` that is because we are going to reflect all those values in the `DosedOpryski`

```
data class DosedOpryski(
    val name: String, val what: String, val when: String, val multiplication: Int
)
```