# kotlin android rooom how to calculate data's from column with edit text?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, android-room, calculated-columns

As in the topic, how to multiplicate data from column with edit text in AdapterList?
e.g.

```
class AdapterList (context: Context, val resource: Int, val objects: List<Opryski>) :
ArrayAdapter<Opryski>(context, resource, objects){
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
val customView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false)
val area= customView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextSize)
val dose= customView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.id_dose)
val name= customView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.id_nazme)
val what= customView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.id_what)
val when= customView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.id_when)
val profilaktyka = customView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.id_profilaktyka)

val item = objects.getOrNull(position)
if(item!=null)
{
    name.text = item.name
    dose.text = item.dose.toString() * area //<--- I want to multiplicate this//
    what.text = item.what
    when.text = item.when
    profilaktyka.text = item.profilaktyka
}
```

return customView
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
dose.setText((area.text.toString().toInt() * item.dose.text.toString().toInt()).toString())
```

Because you get an editable from `editext.text` and then you convert it to `string` and then parse `Int` from that. Calculate whatever you want and then `setText` with string back.

Comment: if I'm trying to do like you suggested the app is crashing and is an error :  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.widget.EditText.toString()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.farmerhelper.AdapterList.getView(AdapterList.kt:29)

Comment: Please debug and make sure that `area` or `dose` is not null on `AdapterList.kt:29`

Comment: @treesher is `item.dose` an Int?

Comment: in entity "pesticides" column 'dose' I have as var dose: Float?=null, so I changed toInt() to toFloat() and  in EditText i enter value e.g. 0.9

Comment: @treesher did you try this? `dose.text = (area.text.toString().toFloat() * item.dose).toString()`

Comment: yes and  in item.dose I have error "type mismatch, required:Float found : Float?, have you idea how to deal with it?

Comment: @treesher it means that the entity as it's type as nullable float. So you can write `item.dose!!` in calculation  `dose.text = (area.text.toString().toFloat() * item.dose!!).toString()`. Caution: This will throw Nullpointer in item.dose is null. so make sure to check that before calculation

Comment: oh I got it, now when I enter area and click button to show list of pesticides the app is backing to main activity and the error is "E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.farmerhelper, PID: 28813
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: area must not be null
        at com.example.farmerhelper.AdapterList.getView(AdapterList.kt:29)" but I entered the value :(

Comment: @treesher I would request you to debug the code bit because it's not related to the calculation question. Mostly null pointer can be tracked by logging or debugging. You can read about this in depth here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: ``area`` is a variable that points to your ``EditText`` (that you're trying to read input from), if ``area`` is null that means its ``findViewById`` lookup failed - are you passing it the correct ID?

Comment: yes, the ID is correct. Is that possible that when I have Edit text in main activity, I enter the value and click button to go to next activity so the value is not remembered and shows null??

Comment: @treesher Can you please confirm that, is `editTextSize` which is being assigned to `area` a part of inflated  `resource` layout or it's in another layout?

Comment: i had to take rest from this app for a moment. "editTextSize" is in main_activity_layout and inflated "resource" layout it is List<Pesticides> so it is another layout

Comment: @treesher that's the issue. Your id is correct but it's not part of  `customView` so `findViewById` won't be able find that and will assign `null`.

Comment: is there a solution to fix that? in another post someone told me to do in this way but i want to put `editTextSize` in main activity_layout https://stackoverflow.com/a/67219696/15133607

Comment: @treesher yes, don't do `findviewbyId` there just pass the `value` of your `area` from the activity. create a function in the adapter that takes the value.

Comment: i hope that it will be the last question :p I have 4 activites: main, choice(apple,blueberries), choice for what (pests, diseases)and activity with list of pesticides to use for it depends what user clicked. will the value from 1st activity be able in AdapterList or Ihave to pass the value for every activity?

Comment: @treesher For every activity you'll need to pass if you don't want to do that then create a global static variable with companion object.